# How to solve simple math equations from a text file

Tags: python, file, math

I am trying to write a program that solves simple math equations from a txt file and puts the answers in a different txt file. For example:

> qustions.txt:

```
1+2=
4+7=
10*2=
10/2=
```

And then the answers will be in a different txt file

> answers.txt:

```
1+2=3
4+7=11
10*2=20
10/2=5
```

So there are simple math equations in a text file and the answers in a different one. The math equations are only number -  operator - number

Comment: Can you share your code and what difficulty you are facing?

Comment: I really have no idea of how to do this @SubhrajyotiDas

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string

Comment: @SubhrajyotiDas It's not even from a text file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `eval` to evaluate everything to the left of the equal sign.

```py
with open('questions.txt') as fp:
    qs = fp.readlines()

answers = [eval(q.split('=')[0]) for q in qs if q.strip()]

with open('answers.txt', 'w') as fp:
    for q, a in zip(qs, answers):
        fp.write(q.strip() + str(a) + '\n')
```

`answers` is a list of the evaluated expressions on the left side of the equal sign.  `eval` takes whatever string is given to it and tries to run it as a command in Python. `q.split('=')[0]` splits each question into two parts: everything to the left of the equal sign (part 0) and everything to the right (part 1).  We are grabbing only the first part to evaluate.  The rest of the line is iterating over the questions in your file and checking to make sure the line is not just a extra blank line.

Using `zip` matches up each question `q` to the corresponding answer `a`, so the for loop yield both the first q and a, then second q and a, etc.  `fp` is a file object that we opened for writing.  `fp.write` tells python to write to disk the string argument.  I am using `q.strip()` to remove the newline characters, appending the answer as a string, and then adding a newline character to the end.

Comment: what is this fp.write? it gives me an error as well

Comment: oops.  literal_eval should be eval

Comment: what version of Python are you using?  this only works for 3.6 or higher

Comment: Oooo I am using 2.7. But can you explain the last 2 lines?

Comment: Ok.  Updated to remove f-string reference.  Also, switch to python 3.

Comment: yeah it works can you just explain "answers" and the last 2 lines?

Comment: Ok, added more explanation.  For more details you should really look into a introduction to Python.  All of the functionality here is fairly basic.

Comment: Can you explain the zip again? I am not sure that I got that

Comment: And yet I still don't understand why would you use zip what does it print? the answer? like because of that you can print a which 'a' is the answer, but I still don't understand why

Answer (score 0):

That's how I ended up doing it:

```
with open('questions.txt') as fp:
    qs = fp.readlines() # reading the qustion file
with open('answers.txt', 'w') as fp:# writing the text file by the name fp
    for q in qs:
        Deleteequal = q.split('=')
        a = eval(Deleteequal[0]) # always going to be line 0 because I am reading a line by line
        f = q + str(a)
        f = f.replace("\n", "") # for some reason it printed the numbers really weird if I've just did f.write(q+str(a)+'\n') the result would be 1 line down for some reason
        fp.write(f)
        fp.write('\n')
# str(a) to write the final answer
```